# Angular ErrorInterceptor unit test not working as expected

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, interceptor

I have an Angular 9 project which uses an error interceptor. The code looks as follows:

```
constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService) { }

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
        retry(2),
        catchError(err => {
            return throwError(this.handleError(err));
        })
    );
}

private handleError(err) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (err instanceof ErrorEvent) {
        errorMessage = `Error: ${err.error.message}`;
    } else if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) { 
        errorMessage = this.handleServerSideError(err);
    } else if (err instanceof Error) { // server side body error
        errorMessage = `Error: ${err.message}`;
    }

    if(errorMessage != "")
    {
        this.notificationService.showError(errorMessage, this.somethingWentWrong);
    }

    return errorMessage;
}

private handleServerSideError(err: HttpErrorResponse): string {
    let errorMessage = '';
    switch (err.status) {
        case 401:
            errorMessage = this.getInvalidCredentials;
            break;
        case 403:
            errorMessage = this.getNotauthorised;
            break;
        case 409:
            errorMessage = this.actionAlreadyBeingPerformed;
            break;
    }
    return errorMessage;
}
```

But the tests written by me doesnt work. It says that it is successfull but if I change the expect->toEqual to another string, it still is succesfully. So my unit test doesnt work. I have a feeling that I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what. What I want to test is as follows "testing a failed get request". The code you can find below:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule, ToastrModule.forRoot() ],
        providers: [ ErrorInterceptor,
            NotificationService,
            { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true }
          ]
    });
    
    notificationService = TestBed.inject(NotificationService);
    httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    errorInterceptor = TestBed.inject(ErrorInterceptor);
});

it('should handle error of type Error',() => { 
    var notificationServiceSpy = spyOn(notificationService, "showError");
    
    // Make an HTTP GET request
    httpClient.get<Data>("url").subscribe(
        (error: Error) => {
            expect(error.message).toEqual("Error: the error message");
            expect(notificationServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Error: the error message", "Er is iets mis gegaan")
        }
    );

    // The following `expectOne()` will match the request's URL.
    const req = httpMock.expectOne("url")

    // Respond with mock error
    req.flush('', { status: 401, statusText: 'the error message' });
});
```

Comment: `req.error(new ErrorEvent('the error message'), {status: 401});`

Comment: I have 2 types of error. Error, EventError, and HttpErrorResponse.. but I cant pass those..

Comment: `req.error(new HttpErrorResponse({error: 'the error message', status: 401}));` does not work ?

Comment: It says "is not assignable to type ErrorEvent"

Comment: `req.error(new HttpErrorResponse({error: 'the error message', status: 401}) as any);` ?

Comment: That works indeed, now I dont get a red line. But the unit test still passes at this line "expect(notificationServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith". It should call that.. and also if I put a random value in here "expect(error.message).toEqual" it also succeeds.. do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

- First, you need to use the `error` method and not `flush`
- Then this is an asynchronous test so you need to tell `jasmine` when the test is complete using the `done` function for example:

  ```
  it('should handle error of type Error',(done) => { 
    var notificationServiceSpy = spyOn(notificationService, "showError");

    // Make an HTTP GET request
    httpClient.get<Data>("url").subscribe(() => {},
        (error: Error) => {
            expect(error.message).toEqual("Error: the error message");
            expect(notificationServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Error: the error message", "Er is iets mis gegaan");
           done(); // Inform jasmine that test is over
        }
    );

    // The following `expectOne()` will match the request's URL.
    const req = httpMock.expectOne("url")

    // Respond with mock error
    req.error(new HttpErrorResponse({error: 'the error message', status: 401}) as any);
  });
  ```

Comment: why new HttpErrorResponse instead of new Error. Bcs there is Error, HttpErrorResponse, and EventError. Or am I wrong?

Comment: it is just an example to match one of the `instance of` in `handleError` method

Comment: If i use this code:                 expect(error.message).toEqual("Error: thffe error message");
 it still succeeds.. I used your code, but It should fail because of the "thffe".. i cant fix that.

Comment: does the `(error: Error)` method called ?

Comment: var notificationServiceSpy = spyOn(notificationService, "showError");
        
        httpClient.get<Data>("url").subscribe(
            (error: Error) => {
                expect(error.message).toEqual("Error: thffe error message");
                expect(notificationServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Error: the error message", "Er is iets mis gegaan");
                done(); // Inform jasmine that test is over
            }
        );

        const req = httpMock.expectOne("url")

        req.error(new Error('the error message') as any);

Comment: I dont think the method is being called no.. but why should it not being called.. weird

Comment: and with `req.error(new ErrorEvent({error: 'the error message', status: 401}) as any);` is it called ?

Comment: That gives the error "argument of type .. is not asignable of type string"

Comment: I've updated my response, there is another mistake in this line: `httpClient.get<Data>("url").subscribe`. The subscribe method accepts two arguments, first one is success function, and second one is error function.

Comment: I think we are close. "Async function did not complete within 5000ms" is the error now. Becuase of the done I think

Comment: yes that means that the `done` function is never called maybe because the `expect(error.message).toEqual("Error: thffe error message")` is failing this time ?

Comment: nope I already changed that to "the" again

Comment: I think it has to do with         req.error(new Error('the error message') as any)

Comment: Yes for me it works with `req.error(new HttpErrorResponse({error: 'the error message', status: 401}) as any);`

Comment: That is very weird.. that doesnt work for me also, still complains about not reaching the place. But I think that you have helped me enough.. it's taking to much time of your day. I'm sorry. I will try to find a solution, thanks man!